# SpringBoot-Hibernate-Mysql id primary key value sequence is shared in all of my domain using @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two classes/domains (`Person`) and (`Account`), they both have id field with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.AUTO)` or any other `GeneratedType`, but saving domains cause them to share the sequence of Primary key.

When I save a person domain, it will use `id=1`, then saving a account will use `id=2` even though they are completely different domain, I don't want this, been searching for quite a while but I don't know the keyword to search.

EDIT: Changed Pet to Account

Im using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

MySql is 8.0

I have a mappedSuperclass Domain Class, but even though I put Id separately per class, it still same behavior..

Domain Class

```
package com.myband.band.domain;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Domain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private int version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

Person Class

```
package com.myband.band.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Person extends Domain {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String nickName;

    private int age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Account Class

```
package com.myband.login.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import com.myband.band.domain.Domain;

@Entity
public class Account extends Domain {

    private String username;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(String username) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add in your `Person` and `Pet` class. Also please include the method where you generate/fill/save the objects.

Comment: It would be good if you post spring and hibernate version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, your table is not created with the auto increment feature in mysql. If you want to use that feature for the primary key, use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead.

Please refer [Gergely Bacso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875779/909876)'s answer to understand how `GenerationType.AUTO` works.

Comment: Identity works, thanks. I was under the impression that MySql uses that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by changing your ID definition to:

`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pet_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pet_generator", sequenceName = "pet_seq")`

What currently happening to you is:

You defined `"AUTO"` ID generation logic, this has defaulted to using DB sequences, but **because you have not specified any sequence, Hibernate decided to use a single, common sequence**, that is shared between all entity definitions.

Comment: This didnt work, I also have a superclass for both of them, but on MappedSuperclass annotation, which has the id field.

Comment: In that case you should really not be surprised to have a shared ID object. If you want them separated, you need to start defining them on entityclass level, and specifying individual `generators`.

Comment: No, even if I put the id separately it still does it also the Domain class is mappedSuperclass, it means  that the child classes is the owner of the class. This is also what we do in work, so I am at lost why it isnt working, maybe there a config im not setting. Domain class is not an entity in my design